# Route with parameter "/api/squareroot/2.0" where 2.0 needs extracting

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask view where the last piece of the route needs to be a float value that gets operated on by a math function, square root for example.

How do I code that in the `@app.route`?

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
from flask import Flask, request
#from functools import wraps
from flask.ext.httpauth import HTTPDigestAuth
import math

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret key here'
auth = HTTPDigestAuth()

users = {
    "robm":"welcome"
}

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None



@app.route('/api/square_root/<float:num>')
#@auth.login_required
def index():
    try:
        val = float(num) #float(request.args.get('num'))
        return str(math.sqrt(val)) 
    except:
        return "Sorry you need a parameter like /api/square_root?num=2.2" 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=4567)
    #app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there; your view function needs to *accept* the parameter:

```
@app.route('/api/square_root/<float:num>')
def index(num):
    #     ^^^
    # do something with num
```

Flask will already convert the value to a float for you, there is no need to call `float()` on it again. The only exception you'll encounter is a `ValueError`, I'd limit the exception handler to that:

```
@app.route('/api/square_root/<float:num>')
def index(num):
    try:
        return str(math.sqrt(num))
    except ValueError:
        return "We cannot create the square root of that number"
```